# 16.04 LTS -- comment user-dirs.dirs lines - uncommented again after reboot

Tags: nautilus

in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`, I commented the following lines :

```
XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/Téléchargements"
XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/Modèles"
XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/Public"
XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/Documents"
XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/Musique"
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Images"
XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/Vidéos"
```

But after reboot, the commented lines are uncommented again, although le file says «All local changes will be retained on the next run» 
How can i make the changes permanent ?

Comment: »»How can i make the changes permanent«« : Probably by editing the lines to your requirements. I.e. a missing line (or a commented one) will automatically be added again at any reboot or logout / login . -